# Download all .net PDB's to my computer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, pdb-files, reference-source

In order to use source stepp debugging :

[image]

And to use navigation to sources ,  in Resharper :

[image]

–I must have the PDB's.

But VS downloads every time a specific module.

I already downloaded the 50mb zip file from : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

But it contains a project with no PDB.

**Question**

Is there a centralized place where I can download ALL pdb's for my visual studio ?  ( so it wont need to download every time)

Comment: Source stepping the framework source only ever works for a month or two after they release a new reference source version.  Then a security update or maintenance release screws it up again.  The current reference source version has been out of date for months right now.  Don't bother.

Comment: The constant re-downloading is a issue with resharper when you navigate to sources, it has nothing to do with .NET source stepping.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain if i clear cache/temporary it redownload , my question remains : how can I find the PDB file . ( although according to Hans , I should even try)

Comment: @RoyiNamir ever since Microsoft updated the Refrence Source website to use the new web interface I don't think you can download the offline pdb files anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you post this as an answer ?. I don't like to leave unchecked questions of mine.

Comment: I only post happy answers, the kind SO users find helpful, nothing happy about this one.

Comment: @HansPassant :-)  Like.

Comment: Use other disk drive than C. Sometimes privilege is need to put files in  directory under C. If that  happened, you will find you cache directory is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

For .Net Core, you can use [dotnet-symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-symbol).